# настройки mailer в yii2

Tags: yii2

мне надо отправлять информационные сообщения с одного мыла, а рекламные с другого. Грубо говоря надо настроить несколько емейлов для отправки. Как я могу сделать это? Мне представляется, что должно быть что-то типа такого

```html
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
//            'transport' => [
//                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
//                'host' => 'mail.tools',
//                'username' => 'mail1@mail.com',
//                'password' => '-------',
//                'port' => '2525',
//            ],
//            'transport' => [
//                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
//                'host' => 'mail.tools',
//                'username' => 'mail2@mail.com',
//                'password' => '-------',
//                'port' => '2525',
//            ],
```

Comment: 'mailer' блабла, и еще что то типа advertiseMailer... И вызов соответсвующий Yii::$app->mailer->...   Yii::$app->advertiseMailer->...

Comment: я не нашёл документации по Yii::$app->advertiseMailer Вы не могли бы описать подробнее?

Comment: Вы серьезно? Вы в конфиге назначаете алиас компонента к которому будете обращатся, advertiseMailer будет у вас равнятся экземпляру класса 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer' просто имя у него будет не mailer а advertiseMailer, вы вообще для чего в конфигах пишете те буквы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212266/yii2-configure-multiple-mail-components-using-swiftmailer?rq=1

Comment: всё, понял. Вначале я подумал, вы говорите про некий класс advertiseMailer, который позволяет делать ротацию. Вопрос решён спасибо!